# How to handle dynamic objects and terrain efficiently like Wurm Online

Tags: client-server, game-engine

I have been interested in how Wurm Online handles a dynamically changing map and set of objects whilst still being able to run on a normal computer. I would like to know if there is any information available on how to reproduce the same type of object management style, efficiently, not only in terms of the client, but for a server to be able to manage the data.

Comment: Well this is a specific question. Have you tried asking the developers? Why let us try to guess instead of asking them first-hand?

Comment: maybe there is some sort of theory or related material associated with how dynamic terrain is handled like that? I wasn't looking for their exact implementation, I was looking for ways to implement similar features, efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See MineCraft. In that case, 'similar features' are handled through something like a dynamic 2D linked list of 3D arrays of "blocks" (that is, integer ids for terrain objects)....or so i would think. I wrote a weak clone of the system once, which went something like this:

```
struct block_chunk {
    int[16][16][16] blocks;
    block_chunk *above;
    block_chunk *below;
    block_chunk *north;
    block_chunk *south;
    block_chunk *east;
    block_chunk *west;
    entity_list *mobs;
};

//standard Linked List
struct entity_list {
    entity_list *next;
    entity *object;
};

struct entity {
    //blah blah blah
};
```

That, of course, is not the only method -- I also wrote an implementation using octant-trees, which is startlingly more space-efficient given large contiguous regions of identical matter:

```
struct block_chunk {
    boolean is_leaf;
    block_chunk *TNE;
    block_chunk *TSE;
    block_chunk *TNW;
    block_chunk *TSW;
    block_chunk *BNE;
    block_chunk *BSE;
    block_chunk *BNW;
    block_chunk *BSW;

    //the node will either fill all contents with one block, or store a 3D array
    int *block_fill;
    int[][][] *blocks;
};
```

You probably knew all of this, but if you're interested in knowing how Minecraft (which, after all, was developed by Markus Persson, the very same Wurm guy) manages its server maps with that sort of detail, you'd have to get your hands on the source code -- since there is a vibrant modding community, that is *not* a problem. Of course, there's also community documentation, which is all well and good (except for all of those ten-year-old trolls who inhabit the forums...)